# $f_n \stackrel{a.e.} \longrightarrow 0 \ \iff \lim \mu\big[\big\{x \in D: \sup_{k \geq n} |f_k(x)| >\epsilon \big\}\big]= 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $\{\mathbb{R}^n, \Sigma, \mu\}$ be a Measure Space and $D \in \Sigma$ with finite Lebesgue measure.

Let $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $\Sigma$-measurable function..

Let $\{f_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of $\Sigma$-measurable functions $f_n: D \to \mathbb{R}$.

Then:

$$f_n \stackrel{a.e.} \longrightarrow 0 \ \ \text{on} \ D \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu\big[\big\{x \in D: \sup_{k \geq n} |f_k(x)| > \epsilon \big\}\big]= 0 \ \ \tag{1}$$

> First, why are we using the limit in expression $(1)$

> Second, here is an attempt:

$f_n \stackrel{a.e.} \to 0$ on $D$

$\iff$ by Egorov's theorem, then for $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a closed set $C \subset D$ such that $\mu(D-C)< \epsilon$ and

$$f_n \stackrel{unif} \longrightarrow 0$$

$\iff \exists \ n \ $ such that for all $k \geq n$ we have  $\ |f_k(x)| < \epsilon$

$\iff \sup_{k \geq n} |f_k(x)| < \epsilon$

$\iff \mu\big[\big\{x \in D: \sup_{k \geq n} |f_k(x)| > \epsilon \big\}\big]= 0$

I think I am missing few facts.

Comment: Should $\mu (D) < \infty$ be also assumed?

Comment: @xbh Absolutely. I fixed it.

Comment: @xbh is this an application of Egorov's theorem?

Comment: You’ve ignored what happens on $C$

Comment: Yet Egorov theorem is not an equivalence for a.e. convergence…